# Simple Firebase Auth UI check and app crashes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I follow the following "how to add firebase ui auth" work flow to my app, and I have a single main activity that just changes a text view if a user is logged or not. this is how the code looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createSignInIntent();

    }
    public void createSignInIntent() {
        // [START auth_fui_create_intent]
        // Choose authentication providers
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build());

        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
        // [END auth_fui_create_intent]
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                tv.setText("Signed");
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                // ...
            } else {

                // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
                // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
                // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
                                    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                tv.setText("Not Signed In");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app crashes and the Logcat is empty!

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when the libraries of firebase and firebaseUI are not compatible.

In the manifest file check if your firebaseUI correspond to the right one.
This is an example for the firebaseUI 4.2.1

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
}
```

for a complete list of compatible libriaries of FirebaseUI 
check this link [Firebase Compatibility](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries)